# How do I nest two count() statements?

Tags: mysql

Imagine a three-column table, let's say `TRAVELS` with the columns `NAME`, and `COUNTRY` which they've ever been to, and `DATE` so that there can be duplicate NAME+COUNTRY rows.

--> I don't want to show the actual `NAME` values, nor the actual `COUNTRY` values - just their **count** and only for those that have visited more than 1 country.

It would be a list like this:

> | 9 | 2 | *meaning 9 people have visited 2 countries,*
>   | 4 | 3 | *meaning 4 people have visited 3 countries,*
>   | 2 | 4 | *meaning 2 people have visited 4 countries,*
>   etc.

I'm quite bad at SQL but I guess I need to build some kind of **nested query:**

```
select count(t1.NAME)
from TRAVELS t1
where (
  select count(distinct COUNTRY) 
  from TRAVELS t2
  where t1.name = t2.name
    and count(t2.COUNTRY) > 1
)
```

Obviously this doesn't work, but I hope it shows my general intention. I haven't been able to find anything about this kind of nested double-count, although it's probably simple enough once I see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select country_count, count(*) as people_count 
  from (select name, count(distinct country) as country_count 
          from travels 
         group by name 
        having count(distinct country) > 1)
group by country_count
```

of course this assumes that name is unique.  If not you may want to user the user_id in place of name.

Comment: I prefer this solution because it's easier to read. I just had to add 'my_table' to make MySQL accept the query.

Answer (score 2):

Try it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0762/3

The query:

```
select
    count(*) as people,
    countries_visited
from (
    select
      name,
      count(distinct country) as countries_visited
    from travels
    group by name
    having count(distinct country) > 1
) s
group by countries_visited
order by people desc, countries_visited desc
```

Comment: @TorbenGundtofteBruun, Did my solution work for you? If yes then can you accept the answer please?

Comment: Give me a chance to sleep, read your answer, try it out, and respond :-)

Comment: Yes, it works. The columns in the result are swapped compared to the accepted answer.

Comment: The columns are in the same order as in the example from your question :) But it does not matter